# "I wish I could visit all countries" or "I hope I can visit all countries"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> We use "wish" to talk about things that are impossible, or things that **probably won't happen**.
>
> On the other hand, we use "I hope..." when there's a good chance that something might happen. You can use it **to say what you want to happen in the future**. [Phrase Mix](https://www.phrasemix.com/answers/how-should-i-use-i-hope-and-i-wish)

I have dreame to visit all countries, and I'm working on it, and **I want do it** some day. in the same time I know this is very very difficult, **and my chance is very small to achieve it**.

So, which one of the following should I say:

> - I hope I can visit all the countries one day.
> - I wish I could visit all countries one day.

Comment: If you _hope_ then _can_ is the right choice. If you don't really hope that it will happen and you start feeling wistful then _wish_ is your choice. Both are correct as Henry Ford said, _"Whether you think you can, or you think you can't you're right."_

Comment: If you think you will attempt it (or at least some of it) then use the word "hope" - it's like saying "I will try and I hope I succeed", whereas wish is generally used when you can't see it being remotely feasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[wish](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wish) and [hope](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hope) both express the emotional attitude of the speaker- a desire for something. **wish** can have overtones of sadness or disappointment- you expect not to get something, whereas **hope** expresses optimism- you do expect to get something, usually with reason.

[can](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/can) and [could](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/could) both indicate the real situation, or the speaker's rational assessment of it. **can** is used about something that is possible: **could** is used about that is improbable.

Using the combinations hope/can and  wish/could reinforces the message.

> I hope I can visit all the countries in the world one day.

This expresses an optimistic desire to visit all countries, backed up by a rational belief that this will be possible.

> I wish I could visit all countries in the world.

This expresses sadness: a longing to do something that the speaker rationally considers to be impossible. Note that, because the speaker considers it impossible, they would not finish it off with **one day**.

To address your question: these are two standard forms that carry the right emotional and rational overtones for most situations,  but neither really fits the bill for your situation. If you could combine hope with could, this might convey the right meaning, but this combination is never used about future events. You will therefore have to spell out exactly what your emotional and rational additude is:

> I hope to visit all the countries in the world one day, but I know that it's going to be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can visit all the countries of the world one day. [or every country, no world]

You wish you could visit every country. But you can't, can you?

Could signals the unreal condition of situation.

[please note: I dream OF visiting x some day//I want to do it some day.]

Both are correct. Wish is for suppositions.

Comment: **suppose** is for suppositions.